# Laravel: Paginate query which is ordered by a hasOne-relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Customer model which has many Contacts. I want to create a view / list of contacts which **paginated** and **ordered by the latest Contact**.

Customer.php

```php
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
    }


    public function latestContact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class)->latestOfMany()->withDefault();
    }
```

In the view, I want to show the customers like this:

```html
@foreach ($customers as $customer)

<x-table.row wire:key="row-{{ $customer->id }}">
   <x-table.cell>
      {{ $customer->last_name }}, {{ $customer->first_name }}
   </x-table.cell>
   <x-table.cell>
      {{ $customer->latestContact->contacted_at }}
   </x-table.cell>
</x-table.row>

@endforeach
```

Table Structure

```php
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->foreignId('user_id');
   $table->string('first_name');
   $table->string('last_name');
});


Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->foreignId('user_id');
   $table->foreignId('customer_id');
   $table->string('type');
   $table->string('body');
   $table->timestamp('contacted_at');
});
```

I am struggling to get the correct query for this. Here's my last try which gives me the following error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'latestContact.contacted_at' in 'order clause'...**

```php
return view('livewire.dashboard', [
            'customers' => Customer::with('customers.*', 'latestContact.contacted_at')
                            ->join('contacts', 'contacts.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
                            ->orderBy('latestContact.contacted_at')
                            ->paginate(25)
        ]);
```

Appreciate your support!

Comment: why don't you just use an attribute?

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara What do you mean exactly? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: use `$append` and have a `getLatestContactAttribute()` function which return `$this->contacts->latest()`

Comment: I don't think that solves my problem. I am able to append the attribute. However, I can still not sort AND paginate the result. Either I use `orderBy()->paginate()` which doesn't find the appended column or I use `get()->sortBy()->paginate()` which also doesn't work as a Collection instance can't be paginated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rewrite your query like this

```
 Customer::with(['contacts', 'latestContact'])
                            ->orderBy('latestContact.contacted_at')
                            ->paginate(25)
```

**Updated Answer**

```
 $customers=  Customer::with(['contacts', 'latestContact'=>function($query){

            return  $query->orderBy('contacted_at','DESC');
        }])->paginate(25);
```

In Customer model you need to modify relation like below

```
 public function latestContact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contact::class)->withDefault();
    }
```

latestOfMany Indicate that the relation is the latest single result of a larger one-to-many relationship.

```
latestOfMany($column = 'id', $relation = null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. However, I get the same issue unfortunately: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'latestContact.contacted_at' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from 'customers' where 'customers'.'deleted_at' is null order by 'latestContact'.'contacted_at' asc limit 25 offset 0)**

Comment: Are you sure there was any table named latestContact?

Comment: @maxiw46.can you post database table structures

Comment: No, there is no table named latestContact. LatestContact is just a relationship in the customer model to retrieve the latest contact of a customer (see Customer.php above). I am able to use this relationship in blade. However, I cant figure out how to sort my customer query by latestContact.

Comment: @maxiw46.yes could you please post  table structur

Comment: @JohnLobo Sure, I added it to the original post. See above.

Comment: @maxiw46.i will try inm y local

Comment: Thank you. Now I don't get an error but the table / query is still not sorted by contacted_at. I am confused.

Comment: @JohnLobo I am still not getting a sorted query. Actually, I think latestOfMany should be the correct relation as I want to get the latest single result of a larger one-to-many relationship (`contacts()`).